# Azure App Service returns 404 on POST request

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have a WCF service that I have published to Azure via VS 2017.  I can reach the service using the URL from a browser and it acts as expected.  The service listens for outbound messages from Salesforce.  If I send a message it returns with a 404 error.  This same service works fine published to IIS on a server. Is there a setting in the App Service that will allow a POST to be processed?

Update: I think the issue is probably with the web.config  Here is what I have:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <client />
    <services>
      <service name="WorkflowNotificationServices.CaseNotificationService" behaviorConfiguration="debug">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="CaseNotificationService" />
      </service>
      <service name="WorkflowNotificationServices.CommentNotificationService" behaviorConfiguration="CommentNotificationServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="CommentNotificationService" />
      </service>
      <service name="WorkflowNotificationServices.TaskNotificationService" behaviorConfiguration="TaskNotificationServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="TaskNotificationService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CaseNotificationServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="CommentNotificationServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="TaskNotificationServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="debug">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This works fine on a VM with IIS.

Comment: Can you provide some code snippets? So that we can better help you.

Comment: Has your problem been solved, is there any progress?